# I Have an issue after selecting categories and pushing it in db it is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Here i am able to get categories but after selecting any one of them and saving it in the firebase database is stored but the categories list is undefined. I am applying hole cord here because i don't know where i did mistake and why it is not working for me**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
         {{ c.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

**product-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/category.service';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent {
  categories$;

  constructor(
    categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    console.log(product);
  }
}
```

**category.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getCategories() {
    return this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  $products: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  create(product) {
    return this.$products.push(product);
  }
}
```

**There is the error i am getting**

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `product.service.ts`

```
 $products: AngularFireList<any[]>;
```

You defined the type of $products but never initialize it.

in your constructor add something like this:

```
  this.$products = this.db.list('/products');
```

Or initialize it the way you want

Answer (score 0):

In your **product.service.ts** initialize something that can read your array like in this way

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  $products: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { 
 this.$products = this.db.productList("/yourpath");  `//in this way or something like that`
}

  create(product) {
    return this.$products.push(product);
  }
}
```